# Given a new normal and 2 points on a plane, how do I figure out the other two axis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to find the new origin vectors for a plane with transformed points. I have 2 points $p_{1}$ and $p_2$ that lie on the $x-z$ plane. They undergo some sort of transformation. I now have two points that lie in a new plane, I know the planes normal $n$ and I want to find the new "x" and "z" axis. I am unsure where to start with this one.

I know I could use cross product to find an orthonormal vector to the first two, however I am unsure how that would get me the new axis.

Comment: Cross product between the plane's normal and the vector that connects the transformed points $p_1$ and $p_2$ will give you one new basis vector. Then cross this new vector with the plane's normal and you will get another basis vector that is orthogonal to the first new basis vector.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I'm a little confused on that one though, wouldn't that give me a rotated version of the axis? From my understanding, the basis vectors are not unique. I am looking for a unique set of basis vectors. Or do I have some misunderstanding?

Comment: Basis vectors are not unique. As long as they are both in the plane and they are not collinear, any and every point in the plane is some linear combination of them. Typically, we make the basis vectors orthonormal, but even then they are not unique. Any rotated version of an orthonormal basis is again an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I guess I didn't word my question perfectly. I am trying to find "the" basis vectors that, given the same linear combination in the first basis, will result in the same translated/rotated point. To be easy, lets assume the points are all unit in length.

Comment: So you are trying to find the transformation matrix that maps $p_1$ and $p_2$ to their new locations? Is that what you are really after?

Comment: I guess so? I tried doing it that way but I was unable to get it to work correctly...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer by doing the following:

```
static func getNewAxis(_ normalVector: SIMD3<Float>, _ imageVec: SIMD3<Float>, _ worldVec: SIMD3<Float>) -> (xAxis: SIMD3<Float>, zAxis: SIMD3<Float>) {
    // 1: Find rotation from imageVec about y normal that gives the basis vectors
    let angleToXAxis = getAngleBetweenVectors(imageVec.normalized, SIMD3<Float>(1, 0, 0))
    
    // get basis vectors:
    let unrotatedXAxis = worldVec.normalized
    let yAxis = normalVector.normalized
//        let unrotatedZAxis = simd_cross(unrotatedXAxis, yAxis)
    let unrotatedZAxis = simd_cross(yAxis, unrotatedXAxis)
    
    // rotate unrotated axis:
    let quaternion = simd_quatf(angle: angleToXAxis, axis: yAxis)
    let xAxis = quaternion.act(unrotatedXAxis)
    let zAxis = quaternion.act(unrotatedZAxis)
    
    return (xAxis, zAxis)
}
```

Basically, you cross the normal axis with a vector in the new basis to get a new basis. Using the rotation of that same vector in the old basis "domain"?, you then rotate both x and z axis such that they equate to the same axis in the old basis. Now, any linear combination of old x and z axis will result in the same transformation in the new basis.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).